# Rust - How can I search a vec for a subset - and find the start index of the subvec?

Tags: algorithm, rust

If I have a vec, how can I search this to find whether it contains another vec - and return the index where this subvec begins?

```
let mut haystack = vec!(0, 0, 0, 1, 48, 120, 49, 49, 1, 0);
let mut needle = vec!(48, 120, 49, 49);
```

Such that it returns 4 (the starting index of this subset in the original) (or rather, it would return a Result which contains 4 in this case - and which would error if it is not found at all).

Comment: Hint: use the [*Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm#Efficiency_of_the_search_algorithm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic [string search problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm). @Willem Van Onsem suggested the KMP algorithm, but you should start with the naive algorithm.

For every index of `haystack`, try to compare the string of the same length as `needle` and starting at this index in `haystack` to `needle` itself.

Have a look at this:

```
0   0   0   1   48  120 49  49  1   0
48  120 49  49
x fail
    48  120 49  49
    x fail
        48  120 49  49
        x fail
            48  120 49  49
            x fail
                48  120 49  49
                -   -   -   - match!
```

`x` means that the elements are different, `-` that they are the same. On every `x`, shift to the next element of `haystack` (that's the difference with KMP which may shift more than one element at once).

In Rust, you will write something like:

```
fn find1(haystack: &Vec<i32>, needle: &Vec<i32>) -> i64 {
    for i in 0..haystack.len()-needle.len()+1 { // last indices of haystack are too far right to get a match
        let mut j = 0;
        while j < needle.len() { // check every char of needle
            if needle[j] != haystack[i+j] { // doesn't match
                break; // try the next i
            }
            j += 1; // else: match so far
        }
        if j == needle.len() { // no break: a full match was found
            return i as i64;
        }
    }
    return -1; // not a single full match
}
```

Of course, you can use some of Rust features to shorten the code (and avoid the C-like style above):

```
fn find2(haystack: &Vec<i32>, needle: &Vec<i32>) -> Option<usize> {
    for i in 0..haystack.len()-needle.len()+1 {
        if haystack[i..i+needle.len()] == needle[..] {
            return Some(i);
        }
    }
    None
}
```

Or the functional style if you prefer:

```
fn find3(haystack: &Vec<i32>, needle: &Vec<i32>) -> Option<usize> {
    (0..haystack.len()-needle.len()+1)
        .filter(|&i| haystack[i..i+needle.len()] == needle[..]).next()
}
```

If you understand the naive algorithm and its naive implementation, you can move to faster algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the windows iterator like:

```
fn find(haystack: &Vec<i32>, needle: &Vec<i32>) -> Option<usize> {
    for (position, window) in haystack.windows(needle.len()).enumerate() {
        if window == needle {
            return Some(position);
        }
    }
    None
}
```